# Angular app - change API URL address after building the project in IIS server

Tags: angular, iis, server, build, proxy

I'm currently build an app in Angular, where I get some data from JSON file located on my IIS server. I've created proxy config file to have redirection in my Angular service to get data from my server.

```
{
"/api/*": {
  "target": "<My backend URL>",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": "true",
  "pathRewrite": {"^/api": ""}
}
```

In my service i retreive data with httpClient service:

```
 getData() {
return this.httpService.get('/api/data/myjsonfile.json'); }
```

In Angular development mode everything works, proxy config file changes URL from service and have the data. The problem appears when I want to build the project and put it in the IIS server. In that case app wants to get data from URL:

```
<My server URL>/api/data/myjsonfile.json
```

Instead of:

```
<My server URL>/data/myjsonfile.json
```

What should I do to get correct URL after building my project and sending files to the server? I've read about Application Request Routing and Reverse Proxy in IIS Server but don't know how to use it correctly. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You can use the environment files to set different API URL's for development versus production. And just so you know - this is really unrelated to your proxy as the angular proxy only works in development mode.

Comment: Could you tell more about it?

Comment: You can read more here: https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: This link should help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).